# Generic stack in C using void pointer not working for strings

Tags: c, stack, void-pointers, generic-programming

I am trying to implement a generic stack in C using void pointers. This is not anything big, just for fun and learning. It is working with int and float as expected. But the problem I am facing is with char *, i.e. strings. It is not copying the address of the string instead trying to copy the actual string upto 4 bytes(as in my system pointer size is 4 bytes).

How to tell C to copy address of the string not the actual string, if possible, with out breaking the functionality of int and float already working?

My implementation so far is as follows,

```
typedef struct{
        int top;
        void *data;
        int capacity;
        size_t ele_size;
}stack_t;

int stack_init(stack_t *s, int capacity, size_t ele_size)
{
        /*  Initializes the stack with the given capacity
         *  @param s: Pointer to stack_t type variable
         *  @param capacity: capacity of the stack to be created
         *  Returns : Zero if succesful in allocating memory to the stack,
         *              -1 Otherwise
         */
        s->top = -1;
        s->capacity = capacity;
        s->ele_size = ele_size;
        s->data = calloc(s->capacity, s->ele_size);
        if (s-> data != NULL || s->capacity == 0) {
                return 0;
        } else {
                return -1;
        }
}

int stack_push(stack_t *s, void *x)
{
        /*  Pushes an element on to the stack
         *  @param s: Pointer to stack_t type variable
         *  @param x: Value to Push on to the stack
         *  Returns : Zero if stack is not full when stack_push() is called,
         *              -1 Otherwise
         */
        if (stack_len(s) capacity) {
                s->top++;
                memcpy(s->data + s->ele_size * s->top, x, s->ele_size);
                return 0;
        } else {
                return -1;
        }
}

int stack_pop(stack_t *s, void *value)
{
        /*  Value that is popped from the stack is placed in value parameter,
         *  @param s: Pointer to stack_t type variable
         *  @param x: Pointer to a variable to store the value popped from the 
                        stack
         *  Returns:  Zero if stack is not empty when stack_pop() is called,
         *              -1 Otherwise
         */
        if (stack_len(s) > 0) {
                memcpy(value, s->data + s->ele_size * s->top, s->ele_size);
                s->top--;
                return 0;
        } else {
                return -1;
        }
}
```

For complete implementation of stack please refer [here](https://github.com/ysaimanojkumar/ds-c/blob/master/src/stack.c)

Usage of the above stack is as follows:
Actually there is lot of unrelated stuff like using pseudo random number generator to
insert random numbers into stack.

```
#include"../src/stack.h"

START_TEST(int_push_pop)
{
        stack_t s;
        int n = random() % 60267;
        int *a = calloc(n, sizeof (int));
        ck_assert_int_eq(stack_init(&s, n, sizeof (int)), 0);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i = 0; i--) {
                int value;
                int x = stack_pop(&s, &value);
                ck_assert_int_eq(x, 0);
                ck_assert_int_eq(value, a[i]);
                x = stack_len(&s);
                ck_assert_int_eq(x, i);
        }
        stack_clear(&s);
        stack_destroy(&s);
}

END_TEST

START_TEST(float_push_pop)
{
/* similar to int_push_pop, so ignored here. */
}

END_TEST


START_TEST(string_push_pop)
{
        stack_t s;

        char *str = "stack overflow";
        stack_push(&s, str);
        char **popval = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        stack_pop(&s, popval);
        printf("%s\n", popval);

        stack_destroy(&s);

}

END_TEST


Suite* stack_suite()
{
        Suite *s = suite_create("Stack");

        TCase *tc_int = tcase_create("int");
        /* Stack int data type Test Case*/

        TCase *tc_float = tcase_create("float");
        /* Stack float data type Test Case*/

        tcase_add_test(tc_int, int_push_pop);
        tcase_add_test(tc_float, float_push_pop);

        suite_add_tcase(s, tc_int);
        suite_add_tcase(s, tc_float);

        return s;
}


int main()
{
        int number_failed;
        Suite *s = stack_suite();
        SRunner *sr = srunner_create(s);
        srunner_run_all(sr, CK_NORMAL);
        number_failed = srunner_ntests_failed(sr);
        srunner_free(sr);

        return (number_failed == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Congrats for documenting your API! May I suggest that you swap those success/failure return values `0` and `-1`? If you return `0` for failure and `-1` (or any other non-zero value) for success, you can have somewhat more intuitive tests: `!stack_init(…)` will then signify failure instead of success (read out `!` as "not").

Comment: @stakx: I thought that way too, but in future if I want to return specific error codes instead of zero for error, different non-zero values can be used. Like 1 for out of memory, 2 for invalid operation, -1 for any other error, etc. And zero means success.

Comment: Fair enough! (As long as you define constants or `#define`s for these error values… :)

Comment: There is a difference between the code posted here and code on the github. Can you edit the code here to reflect the correct one? specifically the stack_push, stack_pop are taking void pointers instead in your github code.

Comment: Also I am not sure how you are calling the functions, that should throw some light. If you want the pointer of the string to be copied you need to pass char** as an argument in the stack_push function.(and the same for other apis) e.g. stack_push(s,&str)

Comment: @sraok: Actually, I made a mistake in closing pre and code tags, reversed them. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Now, I have added the usage of stack.

Comment: @sraok: It works if &str is passed, I am passing str. Got the mistake. Would you write it as an answer for reference to others. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `stack_push()` and `stack_pop()` functions are taking a `void*` pointer, you will need to pass a pointer to the character array(string) that needs to be pushed and not the char array itself. e.g. if you declare your string as

```
char str[] = "hello world";
```

you will have to call the function as

```
stack_push(s,&str);
```